# Meteor.js: how to pass the data context of one helper to another helper?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor, handlebars.js

So if I have a template:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{foo}}
</template>
```

and the template helper:

```
Template.myTemplate.foo = function() {
   blah = Session.get('blah');
   // code to do stuff with blah
   return blah;
};
```

and then I have another template:

```
<template name="myOtherTemplate">
   {{foo}}
</template>
```

and I want the data context of this template to be the same as the previous template what would I do?

It first occurred to me that using {{#with}} might be the right approach but that seems like it would only work if the scope of the second template was already inside the first.

Ultimately I would like to be able to use all helpers defined for one template within another template and know how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are asking one of two questions:

1. If you are using `myOtherTemplate` inside `myTemplate`, the context of the other template will be the same as this one, unless you explicitly pass it something else as the second argument of the partial.

   ```
   <template name="myTemplate">
     {{> myOtherTemplate foo}}
   </template>
   ```
2. If you want to use a helper across more than one template, declare it in a global helper. This will make `{{foo}}` available in all templates:

   ```
   Handlebars.registerHelper("foo", function() {
      blah = Session.get('blah');
      // code to do stuff with blah
      return blah;
   });
   ```
3. If you want to make your own data context on the fly (this is rare), do the following:

   ```
   <template name="myTemplate">
     {{{customRender}}}
   </template>

   Template.myTemplate.customRender = function() {
      return Template.otherTemplate({
          foo: something,
          bar: somethingElse,
          foobar: Template.myTemplate.foo // Pass in the helper with a different name
      });
   };
   ```

   This object is basically what Iron-Router will pass to your template on render.
   Note that you wiill need to use triple handlebars `{{{ }}}` or use `new Handlebars.SafeString` to tell it not to escape the template.

Comment: Your answer is 100% correct, but my wording was poor and its not quite what I am looking for. I don't know if you have used iron-router but one of the things you can do is pass a data context via data:... I want to pass the data context of the main template into the header template. Is there a way to get all helpers associated with a single template into a single object and pass that? Maybe data: Template.myTemplate.helpers() or something like that. (I'll give you the answer either way, just curious mostly)

Comment: The data context is not the same as the template helpers. You should gather up the helpers manually if you want to use them because `Template.myTemplate` has a bunch of other stuff attached to it that you do not want to pass in. You can pass in both helpers and data as an object with whatever you wish, although be careful not to confuse yourself.